# sql simple 3 table join using same table?

Tags: sql, join

I have two tables:

**Table 1**
id, name1

**Table 2**
id, name2a, name2b

Table 2's column names name2a, and name2b are references to table 1's id. I need to create a query that pulls both the names out of table 1 based on the id's used in Table 2.

Therefore, if Table one contained:

```
1 Peter
2 Paul
```

And Table 2 contained:

```
1 1 2
2 2 2
```

Then a select statement should give me:

```
Peter Paul
Paul Paul
```

I've gone around the bend trying to build this SQL and the best I came up with was:

```
SELECT table1.name AS 'name', table1.name AS 'Other name'
FROM table1, table2
WHERE table1.id = table2.name2a
```

Which only gives me the name2a column correctly.

Any help appreciated! I guess I need to do a join, but I'm really struggling...

Answer (score 5):

Start with your 2nd table and join TWICE to table 1 (different aliases respectively), then get the name field from each aliased Table1 entry.

```
select 
      T2.ID,
      TJ1.Name1 as FirstName,
      TJ2.Name1 as SecondName
   from 
      Table2 t2
         join Table1 TJ1
            on t2.Name2a = TJ1.ID
         join Table1 TJ2
            on t2.Name2b = TJ2.ID
```

Answer (score 2):

```
     select foo.*, t1.x, t2.y
     join t1 on t1.id = foo.a
     join t1 as t2 on  t2.id = foo.b
```

If there's a chance that col a or col b is null, use a left join.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using an INNER JOIN?

SELECT table1.name AS 'name', table1.name AS 'Other name'
FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.name2a;

Sorry if I'm no help, not that great at SQL myself hehe.

Comment: Don't sell yourself short... Coming here and learning from others is a great way to LEARN complex queries and understanding better relationships between tables.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you need to reference `table1` twice: once for the plain `table1.name` and again to look up what `table2` is pointing at. You can join one table in multiple times if you give them aliases:

```
SELECT t1.name1, o.name1
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id     = t2.name2a
JOIN table1 o  ON t2.name2b = o.id   -- And JOIN back to table1 to get the name1
```